# Create two containers with the same second volume names

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am learning Docker.  Wen i run two MYSQL containers with -v options whose two volumes names are the same , only one of those two volumes is created on the host file system. Would the second one override the first one or the system keeps the first one ? I don't see any command showing the volume names conflict. Here are my commands

```
docker container run -d --name mysql_1 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=True -v mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql mysql

docker container run -d --name mysql_2 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=True -v mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I check the logs with command `docker volume [name] inspect` and it seems the second volume will override the first one

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-07-24T09:34:05Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql_db78/_data",
        "Name": "mysql_db78",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

The createdAt is the  time that i typed the last `docker container run -v ..` command. But it is strange that docker didn't notify about volume name conflict

Answer (score 0):

You're allowed to mount the same volume into different containers.  Files read and written by one can be read and written by the other.  There's no "conflict" here.

In both `docker run` commands you're telling Docker to mount a volume named `mysql_db` on to the path `/var/lib/mysql`.  In the first command, [Docker automatically creates the named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume), as though you had run `docker volume create mysql_db`, since it doesn't exist yet.  Then the second `docker run` command reuses that some volume.

(Operationally, you can't have multiple MySQL servers running off the same data store, so you should see a startup-time error referring to a lock file in the `mysql_2` container.  At a design level, try to avoid file sharing and prefer cross-container API calls instead, since coordinating file sharing can be tricky and it doesn't scale well to more advanced environments like Kubernetes.)

Comment: if the second ```docker run``` command reuse that some volume then why the "CreatedAt" is time that i entered that second command into the console ? Its more like the time the volume was last updated.